# Java/JSON to JS Extjs timestamp conversion

Tags: json, spring-mvc, extjs, extjs4

I use SpringMVC 3.0 to provide data to a ExtJS 4.0 web application.

SpringMVC date fileds are serialized in timestamps 13-digit by default since I use

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

with `jackson-mapper-lgpl-1.6.3.jar`. I think that the serialization  is made by the `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` that uses an `ObjectMapper` with `WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS` set as true by default.

This is good for me, this is a sample record result  `{"userName":"belan","isactive":"Y","userId":240,"created":1358244995113,"createdby":"dadar"}`

In ExtJS I use a Ajax-Json proxy and I define the created field of the user model like this.

```
Ext.define('Pms.model.User', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields : [ ....
               {name:'created',type: 'date',, dateFormat: 'timestamp'},
                ...],
    idProperty: 'userId',           
    proxy : {
        type : 'ajax',
        api : {
            read: 'users/view.action',
            ...
        },

    }
```

My problem is that Extjs converts create the JS Date object considering the timestamp as a 10-digit timestamp instead of a 13-digit time stamp. So I get dates like

```
22 Mar 40123
```

since the last three digit are not considered like mills.

The only solution I found is not convert the date in the model but formatting the value after in the grid column renderer:

```
,{
        header: "Created",
        width: 170,
        flex:1,
        dataIndex: 'created',
        renderer: function(date){
            console.log(date);
            return Ext.Date.format((new Date(date)),'d-M-Y');
        }
```

Can someone suggest me a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [list of supported date formats](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.Date) in the documentation, your [`dateFormat`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-dateFormat) should be `time` for a millisecond timestamp instead of `timestamp` for a UNIX timestamp.